# Copy old WAMP directory to new installation of WAMP

Tags: database, php

Can anyone assist with the following scenario please...

-I had a local install of Wordpress and CiviCRM using WAMP.

-PC died but I was able to retrieve the Hard Drive and install in another PC as a secondary drive, and all of the files are still there.

-I have reinstalled WAMP on the new PC (C:) and now want to know if I can point the new WAMP installation to the old directory (F:) that contains my wordpress and civicrm data, or somehow copy the data into the new installation - in fact this is the preferred option.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks, Joe.

Comment: When you say "data" are you referring to the MySQL data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the root directory that WAMP is using for the website:

For wamp 2.5 on Windows, use a text editor, e.g. notepad++ to edit c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

1. Change DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www" to DocumentRoot "c:/my/new/path" (Note slash direction). This will change the location where files are served from (~Line 230).
2. Change  to  (Note slash direction). This applies permissions from the old directory to the new one (~Line 252).
3. Copy all content from c:\wamp\www to your new directory (c:\my\new\path), including index.php
4. Edit c:\my\new\path\index.php and change line 40 $server_dir = "../"; to $server_dir = "C:/wamp/"; This changes the location where config files etc. for wamp are read from. Change $suppress_localhost = false; to correct projects links (~Line 30).

*I pulled this from this post: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43522/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver*